# GridView Paging, unable to get the correct Datakey value

Tags: asp.net, gridview, paging, datakey

GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" PagerSettings-Position="TopAndBottom"
    PagerSettings-Mode="Numeric" PageSize="40" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="dsEquipmentGridView"
    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Horizontal" Style="font-size: x-small" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="IREF" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdated="GridView1_RowUpdated"
    OnSorted="GridView1_Sorted" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" OnPageIndexChanged="GridView1_PageIndexChanged1"
    OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
    OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
    BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
    OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" onload="GridView1_Load" 
    ondatabound="GridView1_DataBound">
    <PagerSettings Position="TopAndBottom" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <Columns>
 <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="False" ShowSelectButton="true" EditText="QuickEdit"
     HeaderText="Manage" SelectText="Manage" />
```

For the first page loaded, it shows the correct DataKey value if I click on the command field.

However if I change to the next page of results, upon selecting a record the corresponding value is incorrect. It seems to keep the previous page information. How do I overcome this?

EDIT:

In the GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged method, I used the following:

```
    // Determine the index of the selected row.
    int index = GridView1.SelectedIndex;

    // Display the primary key value of the selected row.
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("The primary key value of the selected row is " + GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString() + ".<br>");

    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

    int rowindex = row.RowIndex;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("rowindex-> " + rowindex.ToString() + "<br>");

    int ID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[row.DataItemIndex - (GridView1.PageIndex * GridView1.PageSize)].Value;

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("row.DataItemIndex" + ID.ToString()+"<br>");

    int Userid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Userid" + Userid.ToString() + "<br>");
```

I am unable to get the correct value after paging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed a while ago. Was using a thrid party GridView helper class. Which broke the normal functionality of the GridView.

Answer (score 2):

When using paging, we can get the exact row index (which is counted from 0 to `totalrows` in gridview) 
and when fetching `datakey`, we need to pass the row index of the current page.

Use the line below to get the current page index and get the datakey:

```
// Get the correct row index since there is paging
int idx = gridViewRow.DataItemIndex - TestGridView.PageIndex * TestGridView.PageSize;
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be late.
But for others, i reply this.

"Rebind gridview again before using DataKey array"

it works for me.
Hope it works for others too.